# pooling lines in a categorical variable with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, format, frequency, contingency

I have a table of size 2775x2, with text only:

```
'Papio cynocephalus'      'Papio cynocephalus'  
'Cercopithecus kandti'    'Papio cynocephalus'  
'Papio cynocephalus'      'Human in vivo'       
'Papio cynocephalus'      'Papio cynocephalus'  
'Gorilla beringei'        'Papio cynocephalus'  
'Papio cynocephalus'      'Gorilla gorilla'       
'Papio cynocephalus'      'Human in vivo'       
'Papio cynocephalus'      'Papio cynocephalus'
...
```

Overall, there are 5 different categories ( = 5 primate species, the same in both colunms),
I would like to build a new table of size 111x2, where each line indicates the most frequent category (for both columns) for every block of 25 lines (l1->l25, then l26->l50, then l51->l75... ->l2775). Why 111 ? Because 111= 2775/25.
Any idea of how to proceed ? Many thanks in advance !!

Comment: what have you tried? Check functions like `unique` or `histogram`  or `strcmp` and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would suggest.

1. Get the text out of the table into a cell array
2. Reshape the cell array to 111 rows (and 50 columns) and convert to `categorical`
3. Find `mode` for every column

Here is some code to generate sample data and demo:

```
names = {'Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Delta','Echo'}';
A = names(randi(5,2775,1));
B = names(randi(5,2775,1));
txtTable = table(A,B); % This is the kind of table you have
```

Now convert `txtTable` to a cell array for reshaping and convert the cell array into a `categorical`

```
textsWide = categorical(reshape(table2cell(txtTable),25,[]));
mostFrequent = mode(textsWide,2); % Find mode in each column
```

Comment: thanks ! good idea to reshape de table first. Then using function "mode", I should be able to extract the most frequent category in each column.

Comment: `mode` is a good suggestion to get the most frequent item, I got lost while answering and used `grpstats` instead. Will update my answer